# Joining two list whereby the last element of list "A" and first element of list "B" are concatenated

Tags: python, list

I have two lists that I am concatenating using listA.extend(listB).

What I need to achieve when I extend listA is to concatenate the last element of listA with the first element of listB

an example of my lists are as below

end of listA =  `... '1633437.0413', '5417978.6108', '1633433.2865', '54']`

start of listB = `['79770.3904', '1633434.364', '5417983.127', '1633435.2672', ...`

obviously when I extend I get the below (note the 54)

```
'5417978.6108', '1633433.2865', '54', '79770.3904', '1633434.364', '5417983.127
```

Below is what I want to achieve where the last and first elements are concatenated

```
[...5417978.6108', '1633433.2865', '*5479770.3904*', '1633434.364', '5417983.127...]
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve that in two steps:

```
A[-1] += B[0]  # update the last element of A to tag on contents of B[0]
A.extend(B[1:])  # extend A with B but exclude the first element
```

Example:

```
>>> A = ['1633437.0413', '5417978.6108', '1633433.2865', '54']
>>> B = ['79770.3904', '1633434.364', '5417983.127', '1633435.2672']
>>> A[-1] += B[0]
>>> A.extend(B[1:])
>>> A
['1633437.0413', '5417978.6108', '1633433.2865', '5479770.3904', '1633434.364', '5417983.127', '1633435.2672']
```

Comment: You can avoid copying `len(B) - 1` items (at the cost of mutating `B` too) by turning this into `B[0] = A.pop() + B[0]; A.extend(B)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
newlist = listA[:-1] + [listA[-1] + listB[0]] + listB[1:]
```

or if you want to extend listA "inplace"

```
listA[-1:] = [listA[-1] + listB[0]] + listB[1:]
```

Comment: Your in-place version looks more pythonic than mine.

Answer (score 0):

One-liner with list comprehension (just for the sake of list comprehension actually :)):

```
[(x + listB[0]) if i == len(listA) - 1 else x for i, x in enumerate(listA)] + listB[1:]
```